# Time fixed effect with a single country

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model

pvexp.result1 <- plm(export ~ partycongress + inflation + crudepetrol + lngdp + lngrowth + lnlcratio, data=private.export, index="year", model="within", effect="time") summary(pvexp.result1)

I want to assess the effect of partycongress on export while controlling time and inflation + crudepetrol + lngdp + lngrowth + lnlcratio. This code trunk didn't work. Please help!